# Ansible how to know what return value is provided by a specific module

Tags: ansible

From [Ansible's official doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#return-values)

> Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable, or seen directly when output by the ansible program

and

> Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable, or seen directly when output by the ansible program

However, the [document on aws_ec2 module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_module.html)

1. Doesn't document return values
2. Has this example, which seems like it actually has some specific return values

```
# Stripped version

# Launch instances, runs some tasks
# and then terminate them

- name: Create a sandbox instance
  ... # hosts, vars...
  tasks:
    - name: Launch instance
      ec2:
      ... # ec2 module specs
      register: ec2 #This seems to be one of the specific return structure by this module

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      ... # some module
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}" # This is where the registered return value is used
```

Question: How to see all possible return values of a module, even without documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you do something like:

```
- name: Launch instance
  ec2:
  register: data_struct
```

You can then output all the values returned by doing this below the above code:

```
- name: print all returned values
  debug:
    msg: "{{ data_struct }}"
```